# Increment var in whtmltopdf / pdfkit to modify page number?

Tags: python, wkhtmltopdf

So I have used whtmltopdf to create a mixed-orientation PDF document, where the first page is portrait and all subsequent pages are landscape, by creating them as separate files and then merging them.

I am using Python to build HTML strings and save them as PDF via pdfkit, then combine those PDFs with Py2PDF's PdfFileMerger(). I am also using pdfkit to insert a running footer into each page.

My problem is that because I am combining separate documents, I end up with a five-page document with a footer that says "Page 1 of 1" on the first page and then "Page 1 of 4", "Page 2 of 4", "Page 3 of 4", and Page 4 of 4" on pages 2 - 5.

Is there a way to inc

I am using the code from here (https://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt, starting at "Headers and footers can also be supplied with HTML documents.") to enable the running footers. Is there some way to increase the value of the 
 [topage] variable on the first page by X, and the value of the [page] variable on all subsequent pages to make them represent my merged doc?

So with a five-page doc, the [topage] variable would be increased by 4 on the footer of the first PDF, and the [page] variable would be increased by 1 on the footer of the pages in the second PDF.

Thank you, but not interested in using any other engines/tools besides whtmltopdf and Py2PDF.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried combining your HTML strings first, then transforming that combined string to PDF? I realize it doesn't answer your question, but it seems like your problems are largely coming from the complexity of your possible solutions.

Comment: Yes, and that was how I originally had it set up. There's no way to change page orientation within an HTML document that's being sent to PDF, though, and it's imperative that the first page be portrait and all following pages be landscape. I had to go with two separate strings/files and then combine those to preserve the orientation of those latter pages.

Comment: If you switch to using JavaScript and a template for page numbering, you can change the JS to set the `value + 1` for your main body, to offset the cover page.